# How to make a python code wait in blender?

Tags: python, scripting

I want blender to execute the part of my code, then wait for about 30 sec and execute the rest code.
Is it possible?
I want something like setTimeout in js
if not, then how do I execute one script, and then another one by one via bash or python script?

Comment: If you simply want to run script one a after another it's better to use the CLI with multiple `-P` or `--python` parameters. Using a timer for the purpose of executing multiple scripts would be a bad code design, because you don't want to trigger the execution of the next script before the previous has finished.

Comment: That being said, Blender has modal operators and timers however this wouldn't be the right use case. If I understood your question right.

Comment: @rjb but if I use -P do scripts launch all at once or in load order of -P?

Comment: In order, as far as I'm aware.